# My OS X app doesn't want to open files it created

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I developed a document-based app that uses Core Data. When I start the app normally by double-clicking on it, it works perfectly and I'm able to create some data files with it. Then I'm closing the app, and trying to open the file I just created through the app, but I get the window that says:

> The document "data.hso" couldn't be opened. MyApp cannot open files of this type.

I did modify the plist file to include the Document Types. As a resource I used:

- http://daemonconstruction.blogspot.com/2012/05/drop-of-file-folder-on-dock-icon.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685
- [Dropping Files onto Dock Icon in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489961/dropping-files-onto-dock-icon-in-cocoa)

I'm really desperate at this moment, cause I really can't think of a reason why it shouldn't work. Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Here is the snapshot of my plist:

[image: snapshot of plist]

Comment: Show your info.plist. Is your app asked if it can handle the file at all?

Comment: So you are using the document based and core data... Any chance you are saving the database as sqlite file instead of your "document" ? Check the folder where your app is and compare it with your AppDelegate and see the files there. I would start with that

Comment: just added my plist snapshot...maybe it would show what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your application delegate needs to implement `- (void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames`