# MacOS .app can't open file by double click

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, info.plist, .app

I have a c++ program, which should get the file name from `argv`, open this file, and work with it.

Program works perfectly well, because: when I call binary (`Unix Executable`) from the terminal, program gets th name from `argv` and works with it, but when I made from this binary MacOs program `.app`, then, by double clicking on file, which program should open, program throws this error:

[image: Sengine Error while opening .mdl files]

And again, if I launch binary (which already in `.app` directory), everything works, but if i run programm `.app` from terminal, program will throw this error again

list of terminal commands, that I tested:

`open -a /Applications/Sengine.app obj/rogers.mdl` - didn't work

`/Applications/Sengine.app/Contents/MacOS/SENGINE obj/rogers.mdl` - did work

`cmake-build-debug/SENGINE obj/rogers.mdl` - did work

I'm compiling program with `cmake`:

`/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build cmake-build-debug --target SENGINE -- -j 3`

File `info.plist` from `.app` program, just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Sengine</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Sengine</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.zolars.sengine-department.SENGINE</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Sengine</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.0.0</string>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
                <string>mdl.icns</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
                <array>
                        <string>mdl</string>
                </array>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I understood rightly, for some reason name of the file, after double clicking, doesn't reach source binary. I can't figure out why, and how to fix it.

Help me please with this.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166716) help? (implement `(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames`)    Or [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9866)? (programmatically changing default app to open file type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a command line program it works as all command line programs, by reading argv/argc. But when you bundle it into a .app directory with a PLIST you are instructing it to use Launch Services and the Info.plist file.

By doing, so you change how it opens files. Using Launch Services, you can leave the application running and continue to hand it over new files without restarting. You had an example of how that is done in your question:

```
open -a /Applications/Sengine.app obj/rogers.mdl
```

To accomplish this, the application will need to handle the [application(_:openFiles:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428742-application) method. Without adding this functionality to your application you would need some intermediate launcher that provides openFiles and executes your application via `system()` or similar.