# How do I handle dragging onto the dock icon in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have set up a SwiftUI app that seems to accept images dropped onto the dock icon, but I cannot figure out where to handle the dropped image in my app code.

How can I handle dropping an image (or any particular file) onto the dock icon of a SwiftUI app?

### Background

With older-style Swift code that used NSApplication, handling file drops on an application's dock icon could be done in two steps:

1. Register the types you want to accept in CFBundleDocumentTypes in your Info.plist.
2. Implement [application:openFile:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW29) (and probably application:openFiles:) on your NSApplicationDelegate.

This is documented succinctly in [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489961/dropping-files-onto-dock-icon-in-cocoa).

#### Creating an app delegate in Swift UI (doesn't work)

SwiftUI apps do not provide an app delegate by default, though. To implement these functions, you must [do some additional work](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app):

1. Create a class that implements `NSObject` and `NSApplicationDelegate` (or `UIApplicationDelegate`):

   ```swift
   // or NSApplicationDelegate
   class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
      // ...
   }
   ```
2. In your `@main` `App` implementation, setup the delegate:

   ```swift
   ... : App {
       // or @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor
       @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
   ```

You can now implement app delegate methods! For example, this will print when your app launches:

```swift
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("App Delegate loaded!")
}
```

**But** implementing the openFile functions doesn't work:

```swift
func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFile filename: String) -> Bool {
    print("test", filename)
    return false
 }
    
func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFiles filenames: [String]) {
     print("another test", filenames)
}
```

Neither of these print out when dragging a file onto the app.

### Scene delegates?

This seems to be a result of some work to separate AppDelegate functionality into SceneDelegates:

> For those who might bump their heads in this, **the equivalent functionality gets called in the scenedelegate now due to the separation of appdelegate’s functionality.**  The equivalent-ish function is scene(_ scene: openURLContexts:).  I haven’t researched if it’s possible to ‘opt out’ of this, but for my purposes there’s no reason not to adopt the new behavior

— m_bedwell on [application(open: options:) not being called](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119493) (emphasis added)

But there is no obvious way to access a SceneDelegate for our code (which may not even be applicable on macOS?). There is a [promising similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498099/difference-between-scenedelegate-and-appdelegate).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a very easy way to handle drops onto the Dock icon in SwiftUI!

1. Update your Info.plist to indicate your app supports the file types you want (as you would in an older app):

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <!-- ... -->
       <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
       <string>Image files</string>
       <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
       <string>Viewer</string>
       <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
       <string>Default</string>
       <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
       <array>
           <string>public.image</string>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
2. In your `body` in your `App`, use [onOpenURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinesubgroupchildren/onopenurl%28perform:%29):

   ```swift
   var body: some Scene {
       WindowGroup {
           ContentView()
               .onOpenURL { (url) in
                   // Handle url here
               }
       }
   }
   ```

— ianivs ([How to handle URL callbacks with new SwiftUI @main startup?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651234))