# Drag-Drop file into the application icon (MacOS GUI app)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, swiftui

I was testing out the drag-drop feature in MacOS with a GUI app (uses SwiftUI framework).

I have modified Info.plist file to accept any file on drag-drop.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>*</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

DragDropV3App.swift

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("hello")
        
        // C function which writes the passed argument (in this case, the string, "Hello") to a log file.
        PrintToFile("Hello");
    }
    
    func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFile filename: String) -> Bool {
            
        PrintToFile ("File open func called!");
    
        return true
    }
}
    

@main
struct DragDropV3App: App {
    
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

When I drag and drop a file into the .app icon, the application launches and "Hello" string is written to log file, but the string - "File open func called!", is not present in the file.
The application:openFile is not called when the file is drag-dropped.

To understand basic swift, I have followed the [official documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).
Some of the links I referred during this exercise are,

1. [Basic Template of SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-in-the-basic-template)
2. [Add AppDelegate to SwiftUI app](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app)
3. [application:openFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428612-application)

I have also checked other stackoverflow answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489961/dropping-files-onto-dock-icon-in-cocoa)) to check if this is right way.
The application:openFile seems to be the right function.

Do let me know where I went wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: As it stands, the `application(_:openFile:)` method should be called. Try a simpler app (ie without SwiftUI) and see if it acts the same.

Comment: I started with a simple console app. But the drag-drop works only on app bundles (.app files) - a GUI application.
I had originally used AppKit AppDelegate lifecycle framework, but there were crashes. I was suggested to use new SwiftUI framework to create a GUI application.

Comment: There are more keys that associate the _types_ of documents - see the [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685).

Comment: @red_menance, With the current setting, app icon accepts files. I think that part is fine.

Comment: @msbit, I did the same exercise in objective c.....without the swiftUI framework. It worked. application(_:openFile:) is called.
But I'm still not sure where the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

env: macOS 14

```swift
@main
struct DragDropV3App: App {
    
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL { url in  <--- here!
                    print(url)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]